# Single Windows PC on wired network has no internet access

Tags: networking, windows-8, internet-connection

When I turned my computer on this morning, it had no internet access.

I haven't changed any settings - I think there was a Windows Update though.

Windows 8, Intel 82579V.

The DNS settings are correct, that is, unchanged and what we have always used.

I can access the network fine, browse shares, see the other machines etc. but the network icon in system tray says "No Internet access.".

I can ping the gateway.

All other computers on the network have Internet access.

The network cable works and provides internet access when plugged into a different computer.

I have tried disabling IPv6. I have tried disabling/enabling the network connection. I have restarted Windows multiple times. I have tried disabling Windows Firewall.

I am at a complete loss as to what to try next.

ipconfig /all dump follows:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : cydonia
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : Workgroup

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Workgroup
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 10-BF-48-E1-5A-0F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f0e3:89d7:b3a4:62ea%12(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.7.25(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, 19 March 2013 10:50:40 a.m.
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Monday, 25 March 2013 10:50:39 a.m.
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::b1fc:7cdb:cdea:a413%12
                                       192.168.7.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.7.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 252755784
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-45-89-4B-10-BF-48-E1-5A-0F
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 121.98.0.1
                                       121.98.0.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.Workgroup:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Workgroup
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: What's the output of `tracert 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: tracert to that IP (google public DNS?) or my usual DNS or anything else is <1 ms to the gateway and then every subsequent hop is request timed out.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the router? And yes, that's Google's public DNS.

Comment: I've restarted the router, and the gateway machine twice previously. This time when I restarted the router, the ADSL didn't come back up, and we lost internet to the whole network. So I restarted the gateway machine and the router again, and bam. Problem solved. Everything is fine. 4th time lucky I guess. So I suppose next time my best bet is just to keep restarting everything, even if that doesn't help on the first couple of tries?

Comment: Does it work with all non-MS services disabled (to rule out things like Internet Protection Suites)? If you put it directly onto the Internet (no router) does it work?

Answer (score 1):

I never figured it out - but it's working again. I'd given up on restarting the router/gateway machine because it wasn't helping after the first two tries. Then I tried it one more time, and the ADSL connection didn't come back up, leaving the whole network without internet access. Panicked, restarted the router and the gateway machine again, and suddenly my PC has Internet access again.

Moral? One, two or three restarts might not be enough :(

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this many, many times on Windows XP (not, so far, on 7 or 8, and let's just pretend Vista never happened, mmkay?)  In almost all cases, it was a problem with the [WinSock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock)  (Windows Sockets) stack.

I still carry around a utility called "WinsockXPFix.exe", which has managed to fix the problem nine times out of ten.  I'm afraid I really don't know how much has changed under the hood between XP and 8, so the same utility might very well not work on 8 - but `netsh winsock reset` ought to do the same; [here's a Microsoft article on the subject](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357).

Answer (score 0):

ping your gateway

ping 192.168.7.1 look if you loose any packet

ping something on internet

ping 8.8.8.8 same here do you get answer, looses on packet or nothing

in both case if you ping successfully, your issue doesn't come your network settings.

It will help to search on the right direction

Answer (score 0):

If you can communicate with LAN devices (default gateway) with no issues then it’s WAN related, simply try pinging external targets or running tracerts on them. Sometimes my Windows notification is a little behind my ipconfiguration and I have to renew it again for it to go away.